# dot (graphviz): how to enforce position of nodes on x-axis?

Tags: graphviz

I have a simple `digraph` that is supposed to represent a lattice - a graph where the nodes correspond to points in time and arcs represent words. Some 100 to 1000 nodes and about as many arcs.

Example structure:

[image: Lattice]

For each node, I have an exact time stamp, so I would like to force `dot` to put the nodes on an exact position on the x-axis

Here is my toy example:

```
digraph {
  rankdir="LR";
  0 -> 1 [label="cat"]
  0 -> 2 [label="can"]
  1 -> 3 [label="is"]
  2 -> 3 [label="has"]
}
```

You can see it in an online dot editor [here](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20%7B%0A%20%20rankdir%3D%22LR%22%3B%0A%20%200%20%5B%20pos%3D%22%22%20%5D%0A%20%201%20%5B%20pos%3D%223%2C3!%22%20%5D%0A%20%202%20%5B%20pos%3D%22%22%20%5D%0A%20%203%20%5B%20pos%3D%22%22%20%5D%0A%0A%20%200%20-%3E%201%20%5Blabel%3D%22cat%22%5D%0A%20%200%20-%3E%202%20%5Blabel%3D%22can%22%5D%0A%20%201%20-%3E%203%20%5Blabel%3D%22is%22%5D%0A%20%202%20-%3E%203%20%5Blabel%3D%22has%22%5D%0A%7D).

How can I define the position on the x-axis of nodes `1` and `2` (e.g. to make 2 appear further to the right than 1)?

Comment: Non trivial.  do you really want the X coordinate to be a function of the timestamp?  What about (long) pauses when nothing is happening?  This could make for a really wide graph.  Neato will let you specify X coordinate, but you need to specify Y also.